# Jsonb array elements

Tags: postgresql, jsonb-array-elements

How to extract data from a jsonb column

Data Table

| Id | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | {"Green": {"value": "250.3", "reading": "250.3"}, "MbSampleType": {"value": "Water"}} |
| 1002 | {"Green": {"value": "0", "reading": "0"}, "Yellow": {"value": "560", "reading": "560"}, "TotalVibrio": {"value": "560", "reading": "560"}, "MbSampleType": {"value": "water"}}} |

Result should come out as follows

| id | key_value | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Green | 250.3 |
| 1001 | MbSampleType | Water |
| 1002 | Green | 0 |
| 1002 | Yellow | 560 |
| 1002 | TotalVibrio | 560 |
| 1002 | MbSampleType | Water |

where key_value = 'Green'

Comment: Which language ?

Comment: postgresql.....

Comment: You should at least deliver a bit of code to show that you tried something, use [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7d161b223d98f48bd92b6cc1c2fffd65)  for instance

Comment: Why doe you expect `MbSampleType` in the result if you want `where key_value = 'Green'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select result -> 'green' as key_value
from table
```

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-json/